# How to assign a hostname to an Android device?

Tags: android, networking, hostname, file-sharing, fileserver

When you connect to a WiFi network, the router assigns an IP to the android device (like `192.168.1.105`). Now when a FTP or HTTP file server is run on the android device, other devices should type that IP to connect to the server.

This IP is not fixed. When you switch to another WiFi network or enable hot-spot on android itself, it changes.

Is there any way to assign a **fixed hostname** (for example `my-pixel`) so other devices could use it instead of the IP (like `ftp://my-pixel.local:4030`)?